# Change the color of a view with a button click in android?

Tags: android, view, buttonclick

This is to create a greeting card application and here i have to change the background color of the view( which is the background of the card) when a button is clicked. When i click the button labeled red the view should change it's color to red. and so on. Can someone help me with this?

```
 public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
      case R.id.btn1:

        layout= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.laidout);
        layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        break;

        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?  How are you using this code?  Where is this method called from?

Comment: for try ... Setting FrameLayout parent Color will not work for you ?

Comment: nope. the process stops when the button is clicked.

Comment: tried my way just get the  FrameLayout paren using findviewbyid and change it's color ans see that working ?

Comment: i want to change the color of the view when a button is clicked. so do i need to do this inside the button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your code in onClick(View view) method instead of myClickHandler().And the id "btn1" should be the id name which you declared in your xml file.

Comment: I did change the event to onClick but still thrz an error in the LogCat.

Comment: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main and some other errors above.

Comment: Can you post all the logcat reports in your question?

Comment: 06-27 18:21:21.689: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at com.drag.DragActivity$1.onClick(DragActivity.java:72)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)

Comment: 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

Comment: the break statement in the switch

Comment: Its a NullPointerException. looks like you have not initialised some variable and trying to access some method on it. Have you initialised the button(using findViewById) and set the onClickListener on it? or may be the "layout" variable is null, because it might not be able to get the FrameLayout in it. Please try to print all this kind of values and then check if none of them is null.

Comment: switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.btn1:
            
            layout= (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laidout);
             layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
             break;

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your myClickHandler will work, try this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your switch case etc...
    }
});
```

Comment: the process stops when i click the button.

Comment: This is how i modified it. and it gives an error in the Logcat and the process is stopped.

 btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          switch (v.getId()) {
             case R.id.btn1:
            
            layout= (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.laidout);
             layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            break;
          }
      }
  });

  }

Comment: the error in the log cat is at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main and some other errors above. The emulator says the process is unfortunately stopped

Comment: I need more... like Yogesh said, please post the full logcat report into your question for me to

Comment: 06-27 18:21:21.689: D/AndroidRuntime(540): Shutting down VM 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): java.lang.NullPointerException 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): at com.drag.DragActivity$1.onClick(DragActivity.java:72) 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511) 06-27 18:21:21.709: E/AndroidRuntime(540): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)